# Identify the ring $\mathbb {Z}[i]/(2 + i) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I have to find an easy ring which this ring is isomorphic with.

I can prove that $5 = (2+i)(2-i) \in (2+i)$ but this doesn't help me further.

My book says the answer is $\mathbb {Z_5} $

Comment: How did you get $2\in(2+i)$?

Comment: I realised this was wrong. I can prove that $5$ is in the ideal, but not sure whether I need that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that

$$\left[a+bi\right]=\left[a-2b\right]$$

in the quotient ring, meaning that you can always choose integer representatives. The next step is to find the smallest integer (in absolute value) in the ideal

$$\left<2+i\right>\ni\left(c+di\right)\left(2+i\right)=2c-d+\left(c+2d\right)i$$

This is an integer iff $c=-2d$, and then that's $-5d\in\left<2+i\right>$. The minimal case is $d=\pm1$ and you get $5\in\left<2+i\right>$. Thus in fact

$$\left[a+bi\right]=\left[a-2b\mod{5}\right]$$

and you finally conclude

$$\mathbb{Z}\left[i\right]/\left<2+i\right>\cong\mathbb{Z}_{5}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you make the last step?

Comment: @Math_QED Because I've shown that your ring has only five elements that behave exactly like $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$. In fact, I've defined an homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\left[i\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ by $$f\left(a+bi\right)=a-2b\mod{5}$$ You can argue that this is indeed an homomorphism. It is surjective, and its kernel is exactly the ideal $\left<2+i\right>$ in question. The last line in my answer is then just an application of the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: I'm confused by the first statement, why is $a+bi=a-2b$ ?